# Traefik - proxy to backend for angular application

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy, traefik

I have set up a proxy with Nginx which is as follows

```
    server {
       listen       80;
       server_name  localhost;

       location /api {
          proxy_pass https://api.mydomain.com/;
       }

       location / {
         root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
         index  index.html index.htm;      
       }

       error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
       location = /50x.html {
          root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
       }
    }
```

my  Dockerfile

```
       FROM node:12-alpine as builder
       WORKDIR /workspace
       COPY ./package.json ./
       RUN npm install
       COPY . .
      RUN npm run build

      FROM nginx
      COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      COPY --from=builder /app/www /usr/share/nginx/html
      EXPOSE 80
      CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

This works fine But wants to replace Nginx with **Traefik** for the above proxy settings. Any help would be much appreciated since I'm very new to traefik.

Comment: For traefik, you use it inside a Kubernetes cluster?
How do you configure Traefik? with a static file? or by using other way?

Comment: I use it inside a Kubernetes cluster.

Comment: Ok, and it's traefik version 1,7 or 2+ (Traefik change a lot of thing in the 2.0 version on the configuration)

Comment: its traefik 2 +

Answer (score 1):

With Traefik 2+, you need to configure 2 routers:
 - One for the API
 - One for the webapp

For the API proxy, you will have a rule like:

```
rule = "Host(`example.com`) && Path(`/api`)"
```

And the webapp will juste have the host as rule

```
rule = "Host(`example.com`)"
```

For kubernetes, you can do it in an ingress like that:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: simpleingressroute
  namespace: default
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
  - match: Host(`example.com`) && PathPrefix(`/api`)
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: mywebapp-svc
      port: 80
  - match: Host(`example.com`)
    Kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: myapi-svc
      port: 80
```

If the API is not inside the kubernetes cluster, you can define the rule tu use an externalService like that:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapi-svc
  namespace: default
spec:
  externalName: api.mydomain.com
  type: ExternalName
```

Comment: API is not inside the Kubernetes cluster. @jmaitrehenry, Also This config file will be in the toml file right ?

Comment: Its Traefik 2+ version

Comment: @maaz They are kubernetes manifest.
I just presume you use Traefik as an ingress controler in Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to step up from that manual configuration, you may use Traefik as described [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ubuntu-docker-traefik-proxy/#step-install-docker-compose). Watch how he uses **docker labels** to define how to route HTTP traffic.
I personally use [caddy docker proxy](https://github.com/lucaslorentz/caddy-docker-proxy) in docker (swarm, but not required) which I find easier to understand and use